# Newsfeed sync problem

Tags: newsfeed

I have a newsfeed web part on my front page which is working just fine. On mysite i also have a newsfeed. This newsfeed is also working. The problem is that they are not syncronized. If i write something in the newsfeed on the front page it does not show up in the other newsfeed on mysite. Is this normal? Is it possible to get them syncronized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SP 2013 there is **NewsFeed web part** which displays conversations and event notifications from content and people you follow across SharePoint sites, and lets users send short, publicly-viewable messages. This is the webpart which is present by default in your MySite newsfeed page.

However in all community site by default the webpart added is **Site Feed** web part which contains conversation of that site.(Note: Site feed webpart also have default display name as Newsfeed).

Content of both these webparts  won't be synchronised.

If you want a webpart which displays your mysite newsfeed in any site . Add NewsFeed webpart. If that webpart is not available in webpart gallery, then you can export the webpart from your my site newsfeed page and use it in your site.